# Rename column names of groupby and count result with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

Given the following dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'price': np.random.random_integers(0, high=100, size=100)})
ranges = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.price, ranges)).count()
```

Out:

```
          price
 price  
(0, 10]     9
(10, 20]    11
(20, 30]    11
(30, 40]    9
(40, 50]    16
(50, 60]    7
(60, 70]    10
(70, 80]    9
(80, 90]    14
(90, 100]   4
```

How could I `reset_index` the result and rename column names as `bins` and `counts`? Thanks.

```
      bins    counts
0   (0, 10]     9
1   (10, 20]    11
2   (20, 30]    11
3   (30, 40]    9
4   (40, 50]    16
5   (50, 60]    7
6   (60, 70]    10
7   (70, 80]    9
8   (80, 90]    14
9   (90, 100]   4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is use `rename` for Series from `pd.cut`, so if select column `price` for processing groups output is `Series`, so add [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with `name` parameter for `2 columns DataFrame`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(pd.cut(df.price, ranges).rename('bins'))['price'].count()
         .reset_index(name='counts'))
print (df1)
        bins  counts
0    (0, 10]      13
1   (10, 20]      13
2   (20, 30]       9
3   (30, 40]       9
4   (40, 50]       7
5   (50, 60]       9
6   (60, 70]       9
7   (70, 80]      12
8   (80, 90]       9
9  (90, 100]       9
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is much better.

Answer (score 4):

This code works but not concise enough, if you have other options, welcome to share:

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.price, ranges)).count()\
.rename(columns={'price' : 'counts'})\
.reset_index()\
.rename(columns={'price': 'bins'})
```

Out:

```
      bins    counts
0   (0, 10]     9
1   (10, 20]    11
2   (20, 30]    11
3   (30, 40]    9
4   (40, 50]    16
5   (50, 60]    7
6   (60, 70]    10
7   (70, 80]    9
8   (80, 90]    14
9   (90, 100]   4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   df.groupby('team', as_index=False).agg(my_sum=('points', sum),my_max=('points', max))
```

https://www.statology.org/pandas-groupby-rename-column/

Comment: the aggregators need to be in quotes as well, as shown in the linked example.

e.g. my_sum=('points', 'sum')

I tried editing but needed to edit at least 6 chars, so leaving a comment instead :)